# Extending Horizontal Line to Match Page Margins, From a Section Title

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, margins, line

I am creating a C.V. and I would like to have a section of the C.V. (like "publications") have a long horizontal line following it to the end of the right page margin.

I have gotten this to work with some really messy coding:

```
\textbf{Publications~}\noindent {\color{black} \rule{16cm}{0.3mm}}
```

But this is really tedious adjusting the \rule margin to fit each section. Why couldn't something like this work, to automatically fill the line for the page width? -

```
\textbf{Publications~}\noindent {\color{black} \rule{\hfill}{0.3mm}}
```

I have checked out a few other help files, but haven't found anything. This is my first time asking a question, thanks for any feedback.
[Other Information:]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Configure page margins with geometry
\usepackage[top = .8cm, left = 1.4cm, right = 1.4cm, bottom = 1.8cm]{geometry}

% Colors Used:
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{5D5D5D}
```

## Edit:

Thank you @Bernard, the solution is simple:

```
\textbf{Publications~}\noindent \hrulefill
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Simply use `\hrulefill`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any package I need to use for that? When I tried \hrulefill (as well as a few others) it gives me both a "Missing number, treated as zero" and "Illegal Unit of Measure" errors. 

To be clear, I wouldn't like the actual section title ("publications") to be underlined, just the space following it.

Comment: Wait I've found it, thanks @Bernard I just took out the whole rule command I was working with and swapped it out for the \hrulefill.

Thanks again!

Comment: @Bernard Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Il suo desiderio è un ordine :o)

Comment: @Bernard Addirittura! Che esagerato! LOL (+1)

Comment: I prefer the English version: ‘Your wish is my command’…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to use `\hrulefill`. However in this context, I'd define  a special formatting of (unnumbered) `\section`s with `titlesec`, which has the `\titlerule` command for this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\textcolor{SteelBlue!80}{#1}\enspace \color{LightSteelBlue!50}\titlerule[1ex]}[]

\begin{document}

\section{Publications}

\end{document}
```

[image]